# the meaning of the verb "fail"

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I came across this word (**fail**) while reading a book on complex numbers. I looked in all online dictionaries but I could not find the right meaning. this is the text:

> The mapping by an analytic function $$w=f(z)$$ is conformal, except at critical
> points, that is, points at which the derivative $$f'(z)$$ is zero. for example $$w=z^{2}$$has a critical point at z=0 where $$f'(z)=2z=0$$
> and the angles are doubled (See image below) , so that conformality **fails**.

[image]

Comment: It means that the property of being conformal does not hold is that situation.

Comment: "the conformality fails" is just another way of saying "the mapping is not conformal at that point" (where the derivative is zero).

Comment: so you mean the verb just means ''does not hold" Am I right?

Comment: The condition fails to hold, fails to be true, is false at that point.

Comment: This is rather a language issue than a mathematical one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it means that the property of being conformal does not hold in that situation , that is , the function fails to be conformal

Answer (score 2):

A condition *holds* (*fails*) when it's true (false). For example, primality holds (fails) for $3$ ($4$).

Comment: so you mean the verb means "does not hold'' Am I right?

Comment: @Arashrostami Correct.

Comment: thanks a lot sir